# how to customize styles of tabBarComponent in react navigation

Tags: react-native

I have created tabBarComponent to my Material Top Tab navigator 
navigation is working normal , I can't figure out a way to style my tabBarComponent
that's how I am calling my tabBarComponent :

```
tabBarComponent:({navigation})=>{return <CustomTab pprop={navigation} />} ,
```

navigation as I said its working with no errors , but I try to find a way to style my custom component , if I make :

```
tabBarComponent:({navigation})=>{return <CustomTabBar pprop={navigation} style = {{tabBarOptions: {
      scrollEnabled: true,
      labelStyle: {
        fontSize: 10,
        paddingTop:10,
      },
      tabStyle: {
        width: Dimensions.get('window').width / 3,
      } 
} }}/>} ,
```

these styles do not affect my component , If I went to CustomTabBar component try to style there this solution didn't work , could you please help me to solve my issue , that's how I am styling inside my component

```
      <CustomTabBar
                  style={{ tabStyle: {
                    width: Dimensions.get('window').width / 3,
                  },  activeTintColor : 'white',
                  inactiveTintColor : '#ddd',
                  showIcon : true,
                  showLabel: true,
                  tabBarOptions: {
                    scrollEnabled: true,
                    labelStyle: {
                      fontSize: 90,
                      paddingTop:10,
                    }}
                }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your `CustomTabBar`has wrong attributes which fail to set your styles. For example, `inactiveTintColor` is a props for `tabBarOptions`. So I think your custom component should be like

```
        <CustomTabBar
                     style={{
                        width: Dimensions.get('window').width / 3,
                      }}/>
```

the other props should be set into `createBottomTabNavigator` function or something else.